# Migrate repo to gitlab with null sha1

Tags: gitlab, migration

I want to migrate a repo to a gitlab.
I'm not sure if I'm doing correctly, but what I am trying is:

1. I have created a new empty proyect in gitlab webpage
2. I clone current git (git clone ssh://sergio@XXX.10.10.10:22/git/ProjectDotNet)
3. cd RumboDotNet
4. git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.x.com/sergio/MigrationTest.git
5. git push gitlab --all

When doing fifth step this shows up:

> remote: error: object f8da161b7b526a521d6cd31b4fbb60338d3f27d9:
> nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1 remote: fatal: fsck
> error in packed object error: remote unpack failed: index-pack
> abnormal exit To
> https://gitlab.x.com/sergio/MigrationTest.git  ! [remote
> rejected]   master -> master (unpacker error) error: failed to push
> some refs to
> 'https://gitlab.x.com/sergio/MigrationTest.git'

Doing some research  I have found this:
[image]

But not sure about what else to do to continue...